# The best way to find out that part of the string is potencial RegEx match

Tags: java, regex

how would you do this:

I have a string and some regexes. Then I iterate over the string and in every iteration I need to know if the part (string index 0 to string currently iterated index) of that string is possible full match of one or more given regexes in next iterations.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you plan to do ? I have the strange feeling you're using regular expression in what I can't help but think it's a **wrong** way.

Comment: I want replace lexer in a custom DSL it needs now to lex more types and current solution isn't ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've been searching for alternatives to Java's standart RegEx library and found one that does the job well - [JRegex](http://jregex.sourceforge.net/gstarted-advanced.html#imatching)

Answer (score 1):

What about a code like this:

```
// all of *greedy* regexs into a list
List<String> regex = new ArrayList<String>();
// here is my text
String mytext = "...";

String tmp = null;
// iterate over letters of my text
for (int i = 0; i < mytext.length(); i++) {
     // substring from 0. position till i. index
     tmp = mytext.substring(0, i);
     // append regex on sub text
     for (String reg : regex ) {
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile(reg);
          Matcher m = p.matcher(tmp);
          // if found, do smt
          if (m.find() ) { bingo.. do smt! }
     }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Matcher.lookingAt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt%28%29) to try to match as much as possible from a given input, but not requiring the whole input to match (`.matches()` would require the full input to match and `.find()` would not require the match to start at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the Java regular expression API provides such "incremental" or "step-by-step" search.

What you could do however, is to formulate your expression using [reluctant quantifiers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

> *[...] The reluctant quantifiers, however, take the opposite approach: They start at the beginning of the input string, then reluctantly **eat one character at a time looking for a match**. The last thing they try is the entire input string. [...]*

---

If this isn't viable in your case, you could use the [`Matcher.setRegion`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#region%28int,%20int%29) method to incrementally increase the region used by the matcher.